# Does MATLAB perform common subexpression elimination?

Tags: matlab, optimization

Does MATLAB's optimizer perform common subexpression elimination on MATLAB code? For example:

```
if max(val) > minVal && max(val) < maxVal
    maxVal = max(val)
end
```

How often is `max(val)` evaluated there? Does it make sense to store the intermediate value in a temporary variable (assuming the repeated calculation is expensive) or does MATLAB handle this automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is no to subexpression elimination and yes to storing intermediate values. Example:

```
>> x = rand(10000, 1);
>> tic;
for i = 1:100000
  y = max(x) + max(x);
end
toc;
Elapsed time is 4.297135 seconds.
>> tic;
for i = 1:100000
  m = max(x);
  y = m + m;
end
toc;
Elapsed time is 1.074672 seconds.
```

Even built-in operations like + don't seem to be optimised; a similar test showed that

```
z = (x + x);
y = z + z + z;
```

is faster than:

```
y = (x + x) + (x + x) + (x + x);
```

Comment: The latter is a different situation. In floating point arithmetic z+... Yields a different result than x+...